# Seeking Help: Comprehensive Diagram for a Homemade Accelerator Concept

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, accelerator-physics

My project is based on the paper titled "A Home-Made Accelerator" by Can Altineller, where an accelerator is constructed using amateur gadgets. The paper provides valuable insights into the design and construction of the accelerator tube, ion source, and target holders. However, I am particularly interested in obtaining a comprehensive diagram that illustrates the complete setup and functioning of the accelerator.

Specifically, I am looking for a diagram that includes the following elements:

The Accelerator Tube: Showing the arrangement of glass pipes and rings to maintain potential gradient.

The Ion Source: Illustrating the ionization process, gas flow, and the connection to the high-voltage driver unit.

The Target Holders: Demonstrating the different types of target holders used, including the one with a mica window for nuclear reaction studies.

The High-Voltage Driver Unit: Displaying the connections, components, and modulation of the high-voltage output.

The Vacuum System: Depicting the diffusion pump, vacuum gauge, and any other essential components involved in achieving the desired vacuum level.

I believe that having a visual representation of the accelerator concept will greatly enhance my understanding and help me troubleshoot any potential issues during the construction process.

If any community members could provide a detailed and complete diagram of the accelerator setup, I would be extremely grateful for your contribution.

[Here is the pdf of the actual paper](http://info.ifpan.edu.pl/firststep/aw-works/fsII/alt/altineller.pdf)

Comment: Is this closely related question of any help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/763916/226902

Comment: according to the author he is just building some kind of toy

Comment: The last hundred years have generated a lot of accelerator papers. You are asking for a lot here, way more than I would be interested in doing for you. What have you found already?

Comment: i just want the diagram of this paper [this paper](http://info.ifpan.edu.pl/firststep/aw-works/fsII/alt/altineller.pdf)

Comment: If you want details about that specific design, why don't you try contacting the author?  I don't know how common a name "Can Altineller" is, but the person at https://canaltineller.com/ sounds like someone who might have built an accelerator 30 years ago.  Maybe they are the wrong person, or maybe they have lost their notes, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 1):

In the early 1950's, work was being conducted at Stanford University on relatively short (length of ~ few meter or so) linear accelerators. Principal researcher was Wolfgang "Pief" Panofsky. His papers should furnish you with useful information.

Comment: can you give me one of his papers ? i am not able to find it

Comment: check with the history section of the SLAC Organization at Stanford, they keep copies of papers.